# Bounds on maximum of a finite set of random variables : two quick checks!

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $ N_1 \dots N_n \in \mathbb{R}$ be a set of $n$ random variables. Assume that: (P.S. the $\forall i $ in inside the probability!)

$$ P[ a \le N_i \le b \forall i] = p$$

**CHECK I:** this does ***not*** imply that:

$$P[a \le max_{1 \le i \le n}N_i \le b ]=p,$$

right?

I can see that $P[ max_{1 \le i \le n}N_i \le b ]= P[ N_i \le b \forall i] ,$
and that:  $P[ min_{1 \le i \le n}N_i \ge a ]= P[ N_i \ge a \forall i] ,$  **but**  $P[ max_{1 \le i \le n}N_i \ge a ]\ge P[ N_i \ge a \forall i] ,$  so we should rather have the same true for one-sided inequalities, because: $P[a \le max_{1 \le i \le n}N_i \le b ] \ge P[ a \le N_i \le b \forall i] = p,$ right?

**CHECK II:** But on the other hand,

$$P[a \le min_{1 \le i \le n} N_i \le max_{1 \le i \le n}N_i \le b ] = P[ a \le N_i \le b \forall i] = p, $$

correct?

Comment: Yes x2. You can easily see that $a\leq N_i\leq b \ \forall \ i$ iff $a\leq min(N_i)\leq max(N_i)\leq b$, then the two events have the same probability. Once your Check II is valid, you can easily see that the Check I is true too.

Comment: @Fabien Thanks for your comment! Yes, that was also the argument I had in mind. So to complete your argument: the event in CHECK II is a subevent of the one in CHECK I, and hence the event in CHECK I, namely: $a \le max_{1 \le i  \le n}N_i  \le b$ has probability at least $p,$ right? Thanks!